# Manually sorting a Javavascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create a JavaScript Function that  sorts numbers from maximum to minimum without using the traditional .sort() method

```js
const sortArray= (array)=>{
    let newArray = []
    let firstArray = array[0]
    for(const num in array){
        if(num>firstArray){
         firstArray = num
         newArray.push(firstArray)
        }else{
         firstArray = firstArray
         newArray.push(firstArray)
        }
    }
   return newArray
}
console.log(sortArray([0,10,-1,4,7]))
```

But the code is not sorting properly. I don't know I missed or added wrong.

Comment: if you dont have big data and you dont have any restrictions check this, one of the basic sorting https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: Are you trying to implement some of the sorting algorithms (Bubble sort, Insertion sort...) or are you trying to make your own algorithm? If the latter, I would suggest you look into some of the sorting algorithms and try to implement them first.

Comment: You might need to read about sorting algorithms to begin with. And this has a number of issues which are obvious without even a dry run. For starters, the line #9 which is `firstArray = firstArray` is nonsense. Second, in both `if` and `else`, the value of `firstArray` is being pushed into `newArray`. So there's no real sorting happening as far as I can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A selection sort algorithm to efficiently find and swap elements, resulting in the array sorted from highest to lowest.

```js
const sortArray = (array) => {
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let maxIndex = i;

    // Find the index of the maximum element within the remaining unsorted part
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[maxIndex]) {
        maxIndex = j;
      }
    }

    // Swap the current element with the maximum element
    [array[i], array[maxIndex]] = [array[maxIndex], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
};

console.log(sortArray([0, 10, -1, 4, 7])); // Output: [10, 7, 4, 0, -1]
```

Comment: "Function that sorts numbers from maximum to minimum" is one of the few things the OP asks..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new sorted array by inserting elements with binary search:

```js
const sortArray = array => {
    const out = [array[0]];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        let mid, v = array[i], low = 0, high = out.length;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2 | 0;
            if (mid === out.length || v === out[mid]) break;
            v < out[mid] ? low = mid + 1 : high = mid - 1;
        }
        out.splice(Math.max(low, mid), 0, v);
    }
    return out;
}
const arr = Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => Math.random() * 100 | 0);
console.log(...sortArray(arr));
```

```
` Chrome/121
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=100          |     n=1000     |     n=10000     |     n=100000    
benchmark solutions
    Alexander        1.00x x100k 236 | 1.00x x10k 617 |  1.00x x100 127 |    1.00x x1  131
    Ermi             1.31x x100k 308 | 3.78x  x1k 233 | 17.24x  x10 219 |   16.91x x1 2215
compare to Array::sort()
    Array::sort();   1.70x x100k 392 | 1.41x x10k 868 |  1.00x x100 110 |   1.00x x10  123
    Alexander        1.00x x100k 231 | 1.00x x10k 617 |  1.16x x100 128 |  10.81x  x1  133
    Ermi             1.32x x100k 304 | 3.74x  x1k 231 | 20.00x  x10 220 | 180.00x  x1 2214
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = () => Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => Math.random() * 100 | 0);
const $input =[];

const sortArray = array => {
    const out = [array[0]];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        let mid, v = array[i], low = 0, high = out.length;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2 | 0;
            if (mid === out.length || v === out[mid]) break;
            v < out[mid] ? low = mid + 1 : high = mid - 1;
        }
        out.splice(Math.max(low, mid), 0, v);
    }
    return out;
}

const sortArray2 = (array) => {
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let maxIndex = i;

    // Find the index of the maximum element within the remaining unsorted part
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[maxIndex]) {
        maxIndex = j;
      }
    }

    // Swap the current element with the maximum element
    [array[i], array[maxIndex]] = [array[maxIndex], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
};

// @group benchmark solutions

// @benchmark Alexander
sortArray($input);

// @benchmark Ermi
sortArray2($input);

// @group compare to Array::sort()

// @benchmark Array::sort();
$input.slice().sort((a,b)=>b-a);

// @benchmark Alexander
sortArray($input);

// @benchmark Ermi
sortArray2($input);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```